# To see all integers in same format inside list using python

Tags: python, string, list

Data inside text file(input.txt) is in below format
data :

```
11,12,14, 15,17,18
```

In python script using this above data as input. Below is my code

```
doReg = ""
with open("input.txt", "r") as er:
    for line in er:
        if line.strip(): 
            key, value = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split(':', 6)]
            if key == "data":
                doReg = value

doReg = doReg.strip(",")
duo = doReg.split(",")
```

Output of duo is

```
['910', '911', '913', ' 903', '904', '905']
```

I am looking to data as

```
['910', '911', '913', '903', '904', '905']
```

How to remove space inside quotes?

Comment: If your file has more than one line, you're always gonna get the last line in `doReg` with your current for loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
duo =['910', '911', '913', ' 903', '904', '905']
duo = [s.strip(' ') for s in duo]
print(duo)
```

output:

```
['910', '911', '913', '903', '904', '905']
```

Comment: I prefer not to add any unnecessary iterations to the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
doReg = ""
with open("input.txt", "r") as er:
    for line in er:
        if line.strip(): 
            key, value = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().split(':', 6)]
            if key == "data":
                doReg = value
tem = doReg.split(" ")
doReg = tem[0]+tem[1]
duo = doReg.split(",")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.strip(' ')` before splitting each line to remove the extra space:

```
doReg = ""
with open("input.txt", "r") as er:
    for line in er:
        if line.strip(): 
            key, value = [x.strip() for x in line.strip().strip(' ').split(':', 6)]
            if key == "data":
                doReg = value

doReg = doReg.strip(",")
duo = doReg.split(",")
```